# Proof that equation does not have real roots

Tags: quadratics

> For polynom
>   $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ equation $f(x)=x$ has no real solutions.
>   Prove that equation $ f(f(x))=x$ also does not have does not have real solutions

Can someone explain solution to me? Why?

> If equation $f(x)=x$ has no real solutions than it is either $f(x)>0$ and $a>0$ or it is $f(x)<0$ and $a<0$. 
>   In first case $f(f(x))>f(x)>x$ or in second case $f(f(x))<f(x)<x$ for no real number $x$ it can not be $f(f(x))=0$

Comment: Your assumption about $f$ is wrong: consider $f(x)=(x+2)^2-1$.

Comment: The quoted solution is incorrect.

Comment: @John_Wick Your conclusion is wrong.  Consider $f(x)=(x+2)^2-1$, then $f(f(-0.9)),f(-0.9)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quoted solution should read

> If equation $f(x)=x$ has no real solutions than it is either $f(x)>\color{red}x$ and $a>0$ or it is $f(x)<\color{red}x$ and $a<0$. 
>   In first case $f(f(x))>f(x)>x$ or in second case $f(f(x))<f(x)<x$ for no real number $x$ it can not be $f(f(x))=\color{red}x$.

Answer (score 3):

If $a>0$ then $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c>x$ for sufficiently large $x$. And as $f(x)=x$ has no real root then $f(x)>x$ for all $x$ (otherwise there will be a real root). Hence $f(f(x))>f(x)>x$ for all $x$. So, $f(f(x))=x$ has no real root. Similarly for $a<0.$

Answer (score 3):

Let

$$g(x)=f(x)-x=ax^2+(b-1)x+c$$

no real roots implies that

$$(b-1)^2-4ac<0$$
and $$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\;\; g(x) \text{ has a constant sign} :$$
$(+ \text{ if } a>0 \text{ and } - \text{ if } a<0)$.

thus
$$f(f(x))-x=$$
$$f(f(x))-f(x)+f(x)-x=$$
$$g(f(x))+g(x)$$
will  have a constant sign and no root.