# Nature of roots of $f(f(x))=x$.

Tags: functions, quadratics

Let $f(x)$ be a quadratic function. Suppose $f(x)=x$ has no real root. Prove that $f(f(x))=x$ has no real root.

**My attempt**: Let the complex numbers $z$ and $\bar z$ be the roots of $f(x)=x$. I was able to conclude that  $z$ and $\bar z$ are also the roots of $f(f(x))=x$.

But, I am unable to say anything about the other two roots of this quartic equation.

Please help me proceed.

Comment: Well, either $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or $f(x)<x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3050642/42969

Comment: Thank you everyone, I have understood.

Comment: *Hint:* The fact that $f$ is a quadratic polynomial is irrelevant. The same conclusion holds for all continuous functions $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.